# Verifying mime type of pdf files on upload in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, file-upload

I am working on a project that requires file uploads. I want to make sure it's secure and that only PDF files are being uploaded. I am already checking file extension but i want to make sure the file really is a pdf file.

What is the best way to check the mime type in php? I am using PHP 5.2.5 and can't seem to get fileinfo or mime_content_type() working.

for fileinfo i keep getting this:

```
Warning: finfo_open() [function.finfo-open]: Failed to load magic database
at '(null)'. in [snipped filename]  on line 35
```

Comment: Why don't fileinfo/mime_content_type work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mime types are not reliable for checking type of files. A client's browser might report it wrongly.

Check for [Magic Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Examples). PDF files start with "%PDF" (25 50 44 46).

Comment: reading the mime type from the $_FILE variable would get it from the browser. this is what i was doing. What i want to do is read the header of the file to see if it really is a pdf file.

Comment: Yes.  That's what's being suggested here.

Comment: @recursive for the record, the second line of this answer wasn't there when i posted the comment.

Comment: There were no edits reported, but I guess there is a grace period after an answer is submitted in which edits do not go on the record.  Anyway, no harm done.  I just hope you are able to solve your problem.

Comment: ooh... yes. i added the last line after some research!

Comment: For what it's worth, this is not spec compliant.  Here's a question that includes the full explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731917/how-to-detect-if-a-file-is-pdf-or-tiff

Comment: The question isn't asking the best way to check the type of a file, he's asking how to get the MIME type of a file. The `finfo` functions use heuristics to detect the mime type, not something out of headers or metadata so a client would not be able to have any effect (unless they somehow exploit the heuristics  used to detect the mime type). So really this answer shouldn't be marked as correct, see Mark Baker's answer for a correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, MIME type's aren't the best way of making sure that a user has uploaded a valid file since this can be easily faked if you know how.

But when the file is being posted, you can always check the mime type this way:

```
$Type = $_FILES['someFile']['type'];
```

Maybe you could use a php class to determine it's a valid PDF something like FPDF( http://www.fpdf.org/)

Well, good luck anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

It probably means that the MAGIC environment variable is not set, and your magic file isn't at /usr/share/misc/magic . Either set the value of MAGIC to point to the correct magic file, or pass the magic file as a second parameter to your finfo constructor

```
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME, "/usr/share/misc/magic");
```

or

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME, "/usr/share/misc/magic");
```

Answer (score -2):

An easy way to get the MIME type is directly from $_FILES.
If the mime type contains the word 'pdf' then you can consider it a valid PDF.

```
$contentType = $_FILES['myFile']['type'];
if(isValidPDF($contentType)) {
    die('It is a PDF');
} else {
    die('It is not a PDF');
}

function isValidPDF($mime) {
    return strpos($mime, 'pdf') !== false;
}
```

Comment: This is an insecure method. $_FILES get's it's mime type from the browser and not the file itself.