# Unit testing and checking that PDF has been properly generated

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am trying to easily check that my byte array is a successfully encoded PDF file. When I write all bytes the PDF is successfully created, however I read that a PDF is supposed to start with a particular set of bytes link below:

[Determine if a byte[] is a pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186980/determine-if-a-byte-is-a-pdf-file)

Mine however starts like this:

```
var test = new byte[] { 37, 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46, 52, 10, 37...
```

Would a "SAFE" unit test check to see if these 10 first elements match? For example create the byte[] iterate through the first 10 elements and make sure that they follow the sequence of test.

Comment: or compute a hash for the file

Comment: @Jasen Could you provide an example to go along with that comment?