# Writing a unit test for a function that verifies if a file is pdf or not?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am writing to write unit test cases for my project and relatively new to this. I have a function which checks if a given file is a PDF or not (function below):

```
def file_verify(orig_pdf):
     try:
         read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileRead(open(orig_pdf,'rb'))
     except PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError:
         return orig_pdf, "error: Invalid PDF is not supported!"
     else:
         return orig_pdf, os.path.basename(orig_pdf) + "is of PDF file format"
```

Now how would I write a unit test for this function in python to ensure it is working correctly?

Edit: I was able to write the unit test function so far (based on the information I received online) like this:

```
testdata_filename = 'my pdf location'

class TestVerifyPDF(unittest.TestCase):

   def setUp(self):
       self.testfile = open(testdata_filename)
       self.testfile = self.testfile.read()

   def tearDown(self):
       self.testfile.close()

   def test_pdf(self):
       <test here>
```

Comment: I'd start by splitting the file handling out from the verification function, so that you can pass content of your test's choosing, and so have the tests nicely separated from any filesystem contents.

Comment: If I understood you right, I think you are saying to split the output and separate orig_pdf from the message prompt? Okay, but how would the unit test case look like? I do not think I should be using PyPDF2 again in my unit test case script too. Not sure how the unit case would be setup. I have edited my post to reflect the unit test I have written so far

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6187004

Comment: Why would you return the file name the caller already has? The other strings are arbitrary stand-ins for `True` and `False`, which is what this function *should* return.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to test such a piece of code with integration testing, because there is not much value in testing it with unit-testing.  Your function `file_verify` is dominated by interactions with depended-on-components.  Think about what kind of bugs you might want to find:

- `open` called with wrong arguments (maybe `orig_pdf` not containing valid characters or not being a string, or maybe `'rb'` not being well formed or file modes wrongly chosen)
- `open` called with arguments in wrong order, arguments missing, maybe the wrong function in general - should it rather be `od.fdopen`?
- `PyPDF2.PdfFileRead` called with wrong argument, for example might expect file name rather than file
- `PyPDF2.PdfFileRead` throws different exception than expected
- ...

These bugs can not be found with unit-testing, since with unit-testing you aim at finding bugs in the isolated code.  This means, for example, that you use a test double (a stub or a mock or something the like) for the `open` function instead of the real `open` function.  Your substituted `open` function will be used to check if your code under test calls the `open` function according to your (possibly wrong) assumptions about how it should be called.

To make the example more concrete, if your assumption is the file modes should be `'rb'`, your tests with the substituted `open` will check that you pass `'rb'` as argument to `open`.  However, if your assumption was wrong in the first place, your unit-tests will not help you to detect your wrong assumption.  Instead, testing against the real `open` function will show you, for example, if your modes argument was malformed, and testing against the real `PyPDF2.PdfFileRead` may show that the function in fact requires a writable file.