Django Ninja Unit test an end point with File Upload
I have a simple django model:
class Invoices(TKSModel):
    invoice = models.FileField(upload_to="invoices/", null=False, blank=False, validators=[document_file_validator])
    institution = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=False, blank=False)
    invoice_date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

Then I created an endpoint using django ninja:
@router.post('/add', response={201: InvoiceShema}, tags=["Invoice"])
def add_invoice(request, invoice: InvoiceAddShema):
    instance = Invoices.objects.create(
        created_by=request.auth,
        **invoice.dict(),
    )
    return 201, instance

Not: the InvoiceAddShema is:
class InvoiceAddShema(Schema):
    invoice_file: UploadedFile
    institution: str
    invoice_date: date
    description: Optional[str] = None

Last but not least I am trying to test the endpoint using:
def test_add(self):
    fake = Faker()
    file_stream = BytesIO()
    c = canvas.Canvas(file_stream)
    c.drawString(100, 750, "Invoice")
    c.save()
    file_stream.seek(0)
    file_stream.name = "invoice.pdf"

    # uploaded_pdf = SimpleUploadedFile("invoice.pdf", file_stream.read(), content_type="application/pdf") # <- You see I event tried this...

    data = {
        "institution": "".join(choices(ascii_letters, k=20)),
        "invoice_date": str(fake.date_between(start_date='today', end_date='+30y')),
        "description": "".join(choices(ascii_letters, k=120)),
        "invoice_file": open(r"C:\Users\mshem\PycharmProjects\tks\media\consume\coloombia.pdf", "rb")
    }

    self.superuser_header["Content-Type"] = "multipart/form-data"
    respond = self.client.post(
        f"{self.url}/add",
        **self.superuser_header,
        data=data
    )

But I get:
TypeError: Object of type BufferedReader is not JSON serializable

I remember and I see in my older projects I did it this way. But now the data is not serializable.

I'm simply using Django's SimpleUploadedFile to test
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile

file = SimpleUploadedFile("invoice.pdf", bytes.fromhex("25504446") + b"test1234")

self.client.post(url, data={"invoice_file": file})

The Hex determines, that the created file is a PDF (as stated here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6187004/14698152)
